# How to find a similar sequence of numbers in a list and return the index offset

Tags: python, numpy, sequence

Given 2 lists that are similar but not identical, how can I find the offset of where one list will match the other.  They pixel values of a single column of overlapping black and white images so their values will be close but not exact.  I have grouped the numbers into 3 "bins" (0,1,2) depending on their value.  I am working in Python.  In the lists below, list A starts 44 positions (pixels) before list B.  The numbers after index 44 are "close" but not exact. The expected output would be 44.

**Lists**

```
A [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

B [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Initial Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
B = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


def plot_this(aa, bb, idx, rating ):
    xs = [x for x in range(len(aa))]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4), layout='constrained')
    plt.plot(xs, aa, label ="A")
    plt.plot(xs, bb, label ="B")
    title = str(idx) + " = " + str(rating)
    ax.set_title(title)  # Add a title to the axes.
    ax.legend() 
    plt.show()



x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
A1 = A.copy()
B1 = B.copy()
score = 0
bad = 0
score_dict = {}
for i in range(len(A1)):
    for j in range(len(A1)):
        if A1[j] == B1[j]:
            score += 1
        else:
            bad += 1
    if bad >= score:
        score_dict[i] = 0
    else:
        rating = (score-bad)/len(A)
        score_dict[i] = rating
        if rating > 0.51:
            plot_this(A1, B1, i, rating)
    score = 0
    bad = 0
    A1.pop(0)
    B1.pop(-1)
for kk, vv in score_dict.items():
    print(f"index {kk}  Score {vv}")
```

[image: Plot of A]
[image: Both A & B]
[image: Plot of B]

**UPDATED CODE**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
B = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
def plot_this(aa, bb, idx, rating ):
    xs = [x for x in range(len(aa))]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4), layout='constrained')
    plt.plot(xs, aa, label ="A")
    plt.plot(xs, bb, label ="B")
    title = str(idx) + " = " + str(rating)
    ax.set_title(title)  # Add a title to the axes.
    ax.legend() 
    plt.show()

A1 = A.copy()
B1 = B.copy()
score_dict = {}
for i in range(int(2*len(A1)/3)): #Only go 2/3 way
    coeff = np.corrcoef(A1, B1)
    ranking = coeff[0,1]
    score_dict[i] = coeff[0,1]
    if ranking > 0.9:
            plot_this(A1, B1, i, ranking)
    A1.pop(0) #pop off both ends instead of using numpy.roll()
    B1.pop(-1) #Use numpy.roll() and go all the way around if you don't know which way to go.
for kk, vv in score_dict.items():
    print(f"index {kk}  Score {vv}")
high_score = max(score_dict, key=score_dict.get)
print(high_score)
```

**Final Plot**
[image: Popping both ends and using numpy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it okay to use numpy? Then I would recommend having a look at `numpy.roll()` for shifting the first array and `numpy.corrcoef()` for computing the correlation between the arrays. If your correlation coefficient is close to 1, you have a good agreement between the two arrays.

Comment: I will check that now.  Numpy would be great.

Comment: I used the numpy.corrcoef() to correlate the 2 arrays and it worked great.  I did not use numpy.roll() because I did not want the end data to roll to the front of the array.  Instead, I popped the beginning of array 'A" and the end of array 'B' to move the arrays along the index.

Comment: Okay, I see. You do not even have to pop it. Just use A[i:] and B[:-i].

Comment: I will use numpy.roll() in the larger implementation because I do not know which way to align the array and I will "roll" all the way around.  Thanks!